# String Replace - Add Slash Before Single Quote

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to escape a single quote within my PHP by adding a slash before it. Unfortunately, I've been unable to get it working with str_replace and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

What I have is the following ...

```
$string = 'I love Bob's Pizza!';
$string = str_replace("'", "\\'", $string);
echo $string;
```

When I use this, for some reason it's not replacing the single quote with "\'" as it should.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And what do you need that escaped string for?

Comment: I think the parse error is relevant in this example...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not use [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)?

```
$string = "I love Bob's Pizza!";
$string = addslashes($string);
echo $string;
```

UPDATE: If you insist on your way it's because you're not escaping the single quote. Try:

```
$string = 'I love Bob\'s Pizza!';
$string = str_replace("'", "\\'", $string);
echo $string;
```

You simply can't do what you're doing because it causes a syntax error.

Comment: Hey Sean - I need it to ignore double quotes.